# recover IPSec VPN preshared key

Tags: windows, vpn

So I have set up L2TP VPN connection which uses preshared key. I remember both login and password but not preshared key. Is there any way in Windows XP/7 to recover it?

Comment: Contact the person who set up the other end of the tunnel.

Comment: Thank you, I have done so. Just wondering if this key is saved somewhere in OS.

Answer (score 1):

This is a old question, but on Windows 7, if you used the OS to create the VPN, the information is stored there in a .Pbk's file.

**C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Network\Connections\Pbk**

Other vendor(s) VPN software would use there own path/file format.

Like an example from the Sonicwall GVC client, which save it's settings there in a .RCF file

**C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\SonicWall\Global VPN Client
\AppData\Roaming\SonicWall\Global VPN Client**

Comment: The key is empty in the phonebook. At least for the L2TP/PSK VPN I'm looking at now. Perhaps https://serverfault.com/questions/664580/recover-ipsec-vpn-preshared-key#comment811540_664760 is relevant.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SonicWall's Global VPN Client, as mentioned in @yagmoth555's answer, you can find the Connections.rcf file at `C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\SonicWall\Global VPN Client` ([source](https://www.sonicwall.com/support/knowledge-base/how-can-i-export-import-connection-profiles-in-global-vpn-client-gvc/170505546228318/)) which contains an encrypted version of the Pre-Shared Key.

The key is encrypted with the currently logged in user account and can be decrypted with the following python snippet:

```py
import binascii
import win32crypt

psk_encrypted = "01000000D08C9DDF0..."

print(win32crypt.CryptUnprotectData(
    DataIn=binascii.unhexlify(psk_encrypted),
    OptionalEntropy=None,
    Reserved=None,
    PromptStruct=None,
    Flags=0))
```

Dependencies: `pip install pywin32`

Docs: http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32crypt.html

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You might check whether it comes up with Nirsoft's [Dialupass](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/dialupass.html) utility which "enumerates all dialup/VPN entries on your computer" when you log in as an administrator.

Comment: Checked - no preshared key was found. Maybe OS does not stores the key  itself - maybe it is used for certificate generation...